# Create Admin settings for SugarCRM custom module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm having trouble creating Admin settings parameters for a custom module using SugarCRM 8.2. First, while following [this post](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/28405) I created a new panel on the Admin page with a single link link inside of it by placing this code in `custom\Extension\modules\Administration\Ext\Administration\MonitorSugar2SvcNowAdminPanel.php`:

```
$admin_option_defs = array();
$admin_option_defs['Administration']['MonitorSugar2SvcNowConfiguration'] = array(
 "LBL_MONITORSUGAR2SVCNOW_ADMIN_LINK",
 "LBL_MONITORSUGAR2SVCNOW_ADMIN_LINK_TITLE",
 "LBL_MONITORSUGAR2SVCNOW_ADMIN_LINK_DESC",
 "./index.php?module=snow_Sugar2SvcNowIntegration&action=monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings"
);

$admin_group_header[]= array(
 'LBL_MONITORSUGAR2SVCNOW_ADMIN_PANEL_TITLE',
 '',
 false,
 $admin_option_defs,
 'LBL_MONITORSUGAR2SVCNOW_ADMIN_PANEL_DESC'
);
```

Next, I tried to have the link in the Admin panel point to a form with a single text field, where the administrator will be able to enter email addresses to be used by the custom module to send automatic notifications. The custom module is called snow_Sugar2SvcNowIntegration and the settings are used by a scheduled job called MonitorSugar2SvcNowConfiguration. While following [this post](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/28878-create-custom-view-in-sugarcrm-7x) and the "Creating Layouts" [page](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/User_Interface/Layouts/Creating_Layouts/#Navigating_to_the_Layout) of the Developer Guide, I added layout and view files like this:

Layout in `custom\clients\base\layouts\monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings\monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings.php`

```
$viewdefs['base']['layout']['monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings'] = array(
    'type' => 'simple',
    'components' => array(
        array(
            'view' => 'monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings',
        ),
    ),
);
```

View in `custom\clients\base\views\monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings\monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings.hbs`

```
<p> Hello world.</p>
```

Controller in `custom\clients\base\views\monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings\monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings.js`

```
{
    className: 'monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings',
});
```

All I [expect](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/User_Interface/Layouts/Creating_Layouts/#Navigating_to_the_Layout) here is to see "Hello world" when pointing to `<my sugar URL>/#snow_Sugar2SvcNowIntegration/layout/monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings`. Instead, I see a blank white page. The route specified in `$admin_option_defs` (see above) is actually `<sugar URL>/#snow_Sugar2SvcNowIntegration/monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings`. When I go to this URL, I get a "page does not exist" error. Could someone please point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it. "layout" had to be added to the route in $admin_option_defs like this:

```
"./index.php?module=snow_Sugar2SvcNowIntegration&action=layout/monitorSugar2SvcNow-settings"
```